# Selection disappears when action button is clicked in adaptive cards

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am using Input Choice List but when I click on submit button,the selected value from the choicelist disappears in the card.
Adaptive Card version: 1.0
I am trying to post this card to Microsoft Teams.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adaptive Card clears input on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57870044/adaptive-card-clears-input-on-submit)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57870044/adaptive-card-clears-input-on-submit/57876592#57876592) to the other question, this is expected behavior in Microsoft Teams. You can use the workaround I provided there, or you can ask Teams to change this behavior in their builtin feedback system:

[image]