# After submit, Adaptive cards are not retaining value of text entered in text box - in Web chat

Tags: node.js, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

For web chat, I am using a simple adaptive card.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": 2,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Please enter the email id",
                            "weight": "Bolder",
                            "size": "Medium"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "placeholder": "abc@abc.com",
                            "id": "e_mail_id"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Submit"
        }
    ]
}
```

On submit, it does desirable job at the back end but the value entered in text box in adaptive card disappears. How can we retain the values in adaptive cards after submit action is called?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adaptive Card clears input on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57870044/adaptive-card-clears-input-on-submit)

Comment: Since you haven't mentioned what channel you're using, are we to assume you're using Microsoft Teams?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Yes. I need the solution for web and MS Teams both

Comment: By "web" do you mean Web Chat? Adaptive Cards don't clear their input fields on submit in Web Chat. Why would you need a solution in Web Chat?

Comment: why not in web chat? It is very confusing for user if the data he entered gets disappeared when he clicked on submit. You mean it is abnormal? Adaptive cards by default don't clear the data in webchat?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I should have mentioned clearly. In Webchat, the values of textbox is getting cleared once we click submit. What can be the reason?

Comment: You will have to provide your Web Chat code. You must be doing something unusual, because I cannot reproduce this in any version of Web Chat.

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Yes, seems like front end issue. Almost cracked it. I will share the solution soon

Comment: Did you try updating to the latest version of Web Chat?

Comment: Exactly @KyleDelaney problem was the version of webchat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with front end. Had to update Web chat from version 4.5.2 to 4.6.0 . Seems like this issue is a fix in the recent version of web chat.