# Teams Chatbot,Adaptive Card text clears on Teams Page Refresh

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Working on a chatbot with botframework on teams, while testing we noticed the Adaptive card **input texts clears**,when teams chat is refreshed(i.e if we scroll up or if we switch to some other chat in the window and switch back) before submitting the card.

I guess this probably has something to do with page refresh,Could there be any workaround for this?

Note:-Earlier faced a diff type of issue where after clicking submit on adaptive card the text vanishes but that was resolved via replacing the card with the values/Text with update activity.

Since this is totally teams UI end,Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Text from Adaptive card is cleared out on Submit. This is the default behaviour. However, all the values you send from the card will be shown up under turnContext.activity.value

Comment: i see, so no workaround? plus has this been notified to Microsoft teams community ? Any possible update coming out to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Teams clears out the data from Adaptive Cards on submit, that is inbuilt. However you can work around this by instead updating/re-populating the card with the user input.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57184745/can-we-add-text-field-dynamically/57418517#57418517) to know how to repopulate cards

Comment: not on submit,the question is different.Submit i did the same workaround,how about refresh?